# Initializing Sony Camera API - Camera Stuck

Tags: camera, sony

I can't seem to be able to start taking pictures using the API. I'm able to call several informational API calls but seems like the camera is stuck. Here's what I'm doing:

- Start Smart Remote Control on RX-10 M2 (latest version)
- Connect to camera wifi.
- Camera displays **Connecting...** and gets stuck there
- Call http://camera_ip:/sony/camera/getEvent
- Get cameraStatus: Not Readin (Full result below)
- Call getAvailableCameraFunction, I get back `Other Function`
- Call actTakePicture, I get back `Not Available Now`

How do I get the camera ready to start taking pictures? What am I doing wrong?

Result of getEvent:

`{
  "result": [
    {
      "type": "availableApiList",
      "names": [
        "getVersions",
        "getMethodTypes",
        "getApplicationInfo",
        "getAvailableApiList",
        "getEvent",
        "getSupportedCameraFunction",
        "startRecMode",
        "stopRecMode",
        "getCameraFunction",
        "getAvailableCameraFunction"
      ]
    },
    {
      "cameraStatus": "NotReady",
      "type": "cameraStatus"
    },
    null,
    {
      "type": "liveviewStatus",
      "liveviewStatus": false
    },
    null,
    [],
    [],
    null,
    null,
    null,
    [],
    null,
    {
      "cameraFunctionCandidates": [
        "Contents Transfer",
        "Remote Shooting"
      ],
      "type": "cameraFunction",
      "currentCameraFunction": "Remote Shooting"
    },
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    {
      "postviewImageSizeCandidates": [
        "2M"
      ],
      "type": "postviewImageSize",
      "currentPostviewImageSize": "2M"
    },
    null,
    {
      "shootModeCandidates": [
        "still"
      ],
      "type": "shootMode",
      "currentShootMode": "still"
    },
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    {
      "type": "whiteBalance",
      "currentColorTemperature": 0,
      "checkAvailability": true,
      "currentWhiteBalanceMode": ""
    },
    {
      "type": "touchAFPosition",
      "currentTouchCoordinates": [],
      "currentSet": false
    }
  ],
  "id": 1
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you are calling "startRecMode" before calling "actTakePicture".  You need to call "startRecMode" for the following cameras in order to enable the shooting functions.

NEX-5R NEX-6 NEX-5T ILCE-7 ILCE-7R ILCE-5000 DSC-HX400V DSC-HX60V ILCE-6000 DSC-RX100M3 ILCE-7S ILCE-5100 ILCE-7M2 DSC-HX90V DSC-WX500 DSC-RX100M4 DSC-RX10M2 ILCE-7RM2 ILCE-7SM2